# what should i do with an extra ssd disc?

Tags: linux, hardware, memory, ssd

I have this server setup: http://www.server4you.com/root-server/server-details.php?products=5

That gives an extra 60 GB OCZ Vertex 2 SSD hard-disk. I don't want to use it as storage. What should i do with it? Can i use it like extra ram or something for mySQL cache? What's your opinion?

Comment: Send it to me..

Comment: ZFS could use it for ZIL and L2Arc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea with regard to databases.

[Flashcache, maybe](https://github.com/facebook/flashcache/)?

See: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/05/10/flashcache-first-experiments/

Comment: seems so good but its kernel change which i cant handle with my newbie server management experience :P i prefer some more safety/easy way

Comment: accepting as answer. this is "the" answer but its not something i can handle it seems :P

Answer (score 2):

Is this the 2VTXE60G model or the 2VTX60G? if the latter, cheaper, part I'd forget about using it as a server part. The E-models have 28% of overcommit memory, the non-E model only 7% - this means that you have only a quarter of the additional memory set aside on the SSD to handle memory cell failures. Used as a cache or any other application where writes are common will see these cells fail at a rate beyond its design (35GB/day btw), once this 7% is used up it'll start eating silently into the basic 60GB until you have file system corruptions and data loss. Obviously going for the E-model puts this day off by a factor of 4, whereas enterprise-class SSD are over many times more again.

Think long and hard about using SSDs in routine-write scenarios, they're wonderful things when it comes to reads but their behaviour is not that of simply a faster regular disk, I'd hate for you to lose data and service by assuming they are.

I'd use it in a laptop/desktop myself, it's what it was designed for.

Comment: The semantics of how the write back cache of SSD is handled on your HBA side and/or if it's properly backed by a supercap or not are things that are usually not clear with consumer grade SSDs. Go enterprise grade or use it for booting your laptop faster or something like that.

Comment: well.. in lshw result: description: ATA Disk product: OCZ-VERTEX2 version: 1.29 size: 55GiB (60GB)  i am not sure its 2VTXE60G or 2VTX60G